# How to turn a binary matrix into a data.frame in R? lpSolveAPI

Tags: r, optimization, lpsolve

```r
library(lpSolveAPI)
lprec1 <- make.lp(0,nrow(df) 

  add.constraint(lprec1, c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads1)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads2)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads3)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads4)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads5)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads6)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads7)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads8)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads9)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads10)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads11)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads12)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads13)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads14)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads15)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads16)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads17)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads18)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads19)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads20)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads21)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads22)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads23)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads24)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads25)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads26)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads27)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads28)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads29))
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads30)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads31))
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0), "<=", as.numeric(ads32)) 
  add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), "<=", as.numeric(ads33)) 
solve(lprec1) 
print(get.variables(lprec1)) 
print(get.objective(lprec1))
```

I turned all my **ads** vectors into a single data.frame df$ads, is there any way to transform this matrix too? I tried using

```
add.constraint(lprec1, diag(nrow (df))), "<=", as.vector(df$ads))
solve(lprec1)
```

but lpSolveAPI recognizes that length is different:**Error in add.constraint(lprec1, diag(nrow(df), "<=", df$ads) : 
 the length of ‘xt’ is not equal to the number of decision variables in the model** but there are 33 decision variables and the nrow(df) are 33...
Is there any way to binarize without having to make this matrix?

```
length(diag(nrow(df))) = 361
```

The length is different sizes, is there any way to turn these vectors into a single data.frame with length = 33?

Comment: I tried to use as.table (diag (nrow (df)) too, Is it impossible to isolate each line of a matrix with a function?

Comment: I tried to use as.data.frame (diag (nrow (df)) too

Comment: What package are you using? What kind of variable is lprec1? Please check the output of class(lprec1), str(lprec1), and attributes(lprec1).

Comment: lprec1 is a lpSolve linear program model object from lpSolveAPI package. class(lprec1): "lpExtPtr"

Comment: Looking at the documentation of add.constraint(), it requires argument "rhs" to be a single numeric value. In your case it is as.vector(df$ads), which I suspect has length > 1. This is likely a source of error. This user guide may help you figure what you need to do: http://civil.colorado.edu/~balajir/CVEN5393/R-sessions/sess1/lpSolveAPI-vignettes.pdf

Comment: if rhs is a single numeric value, cannot pass a data.frame as an argument? a data.frame is a vector set

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the package whether you can make such a substitution. I don't know the answer. A "single numeric value" is in fact a numeric vector of length 1. A data frame is a list with particular attributes. Numeric vectors and lists are 2 different built-in data types in the R language.

Comment: What is 'ads1', 'ads2' etc

Comment: it was a vector with 1 numeric value inside, i turned all ads1 ads2 ads3 into df$ads line 1 is ads1 line 2 is ads2 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option, where we create a `list` of vectors, loop through the sequence of `list` and assign the constraints

```
a <- as.vector(diag(5))
lst1 <- asplit(matrix(a, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE), 1)

library(lpSolveAPI)
lprec1 <- make.lp(0, length(lst1)) 
ads <- c(0, 5, 1, -1, 0)
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) add.constraint(lprec1, lst1[[i]], "<=", ads[i])
solve(lprec1)
#[1] 2
```

Comment: @ViniciusSoares Please check my example, where I created the 'ads' as the same length as the number of rows or the length of lst1

Comment: Error in abs(xt) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: @ViniciusSoares. Not with the example I posted

Comment: @ViniciusSoares. Not clear about the error as the `lst1` length is the same as the number of elements in 'ads' vector.  Do you have `ads` as a `list`?

Comment: error: Error in lst1 [[i]]: subscript out of bounds, but if I keep giving ctrl + enter the code it creates lprec1, but the restriction of lst1 [[i]] doesn't work

Comment: i used tidyverse tribble, to turn ads into a dataframe column,

Comment: class(df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Comment: @ViniciusSoares Can you show your code with `for` loop

Comment: @ViniciusSoares Can you try `for(i in seq_along(lst1)) add.constraint(lprec1, lst1[[i]], "<=", ads[[i]])`. Here, I am using `ads[[i]]]` or `df[[i]]`

Comment: library(lpSolveAPI)
  lprec1 <- make.lp(0,nrow(df)) 
  lp.control(lprec1,sense='max') 
  set.type(lprec1, columns=c(seq(from=1,nrow(df),by=1)), type =c("integer"))  
  a<-diag(nrow(df))
  lst1 <- asplit(matrix(a, ncol = nrow(df), byrow = TRUE), 1)
  for(i in seq_along(a)) add.constraint(lprec1, lst1[[i]], "<=", df$ads)
  print(solve(lprec1)) 
  print(get.variables(lprec1)) 
  print(get.objective(lprec1))

Comment: @ViniciusSoares. What is the length of `df$ads` it needs to be either 1 or length of each list element i.e `length(lst[[1]])`

Comment: the length of df$ads and lst1 is the same

Comment: @ViniciusSoares. In that case you need `for(i in seq_along(lst1)) add.constraint(lprec1, lst1[[i]], "<=", df$ads[i])`

Comment: Funny, it works perfectly if I ignore the error message "Error in lst1 [[i]]: subscript out of bounds" and keep pressing ctrl + enter, but if I try to run all the code at once R doesn't ignore this error , can you tell me why this happens?

Comment: @ViniciusSoares. It could be based on the how you are indexing.  If you check my code and the vectors, each index is correctly applied